# How to override specific properties of gradle.properties through Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, deployment, build, artifactory

Trying to achieve aritifactory publish with gradle.
Currently properties are taken from `gradle.properties` located in the workspace.

```
name=sample project
group=com.sample.mico.cluster.service
version=1.0.1
description=sample cluster service
artifactory_username=admin
artifactory_password=*********
artifactory_url=http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/artifactory
artifactory_repo=libs-release-local
internal_repo=http://1xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/artifactory/libs-release
```

Here i need to override the "`artifactory_url`" "`internal_repo`" and password properties through jenkins. Currently jenkins using "Artifactory plugin".
Because it shouldn't be controlled by developers through commit.

But all other details i should be taking from `build.gradle`, like "name", "version".

Any way to achieve this ?